# Way to find all affected locations by variable

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to find code lines, where a certain property can get.
Consider I have property holder class and in java editor look to some setter method. In code is property readed and setted to entity. And before save to database, do validation on server side. So I want see from client.propertyHolder.setter to server.entityValidator.getter

Simple example

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Holder h = new Holder();
        h.setHolder("Something");  // Here i want use plugin
        Entity e = new Entity();
        e.setName(h.getHolder());

        // Consider this is on server side in validator and call only if annotation validation is OK
        Assert.assertTrue(e.getName().length() > 0)
    }
}

public class Holder{
    public String holder = null;
    public void setHolder(String holder){this.holder = holder}
    public void getHolder(){return holder}
}

public class Entity{
    @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
    private String name = null;
    public void setName(String name){this.name = name}
    public void getName(){return name}
}
```

So i should get lines

```
e.setName(h.getHolder());
Assert.assertTrue(e.getName().length() > 0)
```

and be nice if NotNull anotations too

Is there a way, how to achive this? Some good free eclipse-plugin maybye?

Thanks for help. Pavel

Comment: In the _Package/Project Explorer_ view you can select multiple methods and then press Ctrl+Alt+H.

Comment: It is not what I want. That shows only direct call, but not enough intelligent track access by public, getter and setter to sublevels